# What does it mean to present a logo and promo materials in "1:1"?

Tags: logo, terminology, branding

I'm currently working on some promo materials for a company I'm currently doing a logo design for. They asked me to do a memorandum, business card, folder, envelope, and a seal. They stated:

> to be presented in **1:1**.

1:1? Do I need to set some size for my logo or what? I know to get some promo pictures from the net and place the logo where and how I think It should be. I'm just not sure how this should be done in 1:1?

Now it is my first time I'm doing branding for a company, but that's the way it is, I would really appreciate help from someone.

Comment: ...ask your client? Even if the 'correct' answer might be given here, they might have meant something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

You will have the size of the logos. You are designing the following items:

- memorandum
- business card
- folder
- envelope
- seal

They all have a standard sizes (A4, Letter, DL envelope etc). 
You should know about what size are you designing for. Once you finish designing them, you can check the size of the logo you have created on that particular item. They just want a version that is ready to print at the exact size (size that prints to those dimensions in 300DPI - most likely).

The other option is to just ask them. They are your clients, it's in their best interest to clarify. There is no harm done in coming back to the client and get a clarification of the brief. In fact, it will make you look more client centered and you can work on your customer service, because maybe they have some size requirements that you are not aware.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

They want to see the things as they are - no placeholders no sketches, only photorealistic presentation of your options for the final products, also those details which come with the used physical materials.

Ask them do they accept something less.